# Rails-how to select from multiple tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, associations

I am new to Ruby so I don't know how to select data by join tables. My database has 3 tables: `users`, `roles`, and `client_organizations`.

```
users(id,email)
client_organizations(id,name)
roles(id,user_id,client_organization_id,role)
```

I want to show data like this:

```
User_Email                       Role
                            RoleA for [ClientA]
user1@gmail.com             RoleB for [ClientB]
                            RoleC for [ClientB]

user2@gmail.com             RoleB for [ClientC]
```

In Ruby, how can I get data from the databse like above?

Comment: This is really the kind of basic stuff that would best be learned by reading some tutorials or books, rather than asking someone to write your code for you. Check the info on the rails tags for resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your models are configured correctly, you can use your associations. This is by no means optimized, but rather simply laid out to show the logic. You will want to eager load your associations for database optimization.

controller

```
@users = User.all
```

view

```
<table>
  <tr><th>email</th><th>role</th></tr>
  <% @users.each do |user| %>

    <tr>
       <td><%= user.email %></td>
       <td>
          <% user.roles.each do |role| %>
             <%= "#{role.role} for [#{role.client_organization.name}]" %><br>
          <% end %>
       </td>
    </tr>
   <% end %>
  </table>
```

Comment: Thanks,  from your code <%= "#{role.role} for [#{role.client_organization.name}]" %>  ,for each user has many roles, I want the result order by name of client_organization[A..Z]

Comment: You can do the reverse and list each org, their roles and then the users. Order by the organization's name.

Comment: I mean  the result I mentioned above the organizations' name associate with 1 user order A..Z ,for example user1@gmail.com has 3 organization:M,A,F. I want the result: user1@gmail.com A,M,F.And the result similar for another user.Thanks a lot